# Textblock won't recieve trigger in HierachicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm trying to get a TreeView to display items as a TextBlock, and then based on a boolean inside the data-bound object to either make the FontWeight Normal or Bold, pretty much the following:

```
<TreeView x:Name="TreeView" ItemsSource="{Binding Layers}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:Layer}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Layers}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}">
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShowInPreview}">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The Setter outside the trigger actually works, when I set that one to "Bold", everything goes Bold right away. It's just the DataTrigger that never, well... triggers :P

The ItemSource implements INotifyPropertyChanged, and so does the Layer object on all properties (including the ShowInPreview).

I've tried all kinds of different setups I could find on the web (using Window.Resources, putting it in TreeView.ItemContainerStyle, etc. etc), so I'm completely at a loss right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Value on your data trigger.

Comment: Doooohh, you're completely right, how did I miss that?! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly where is your property, try something like this. I think, issue in binding:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowInPreview, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}}}">
```

Comment: The `ShowInPreview` is part of the Layer-object that's bound to the TextBlock (the same one where I'm displaying the Name: `{Binding Path=Name}`)